# what's the meaning of putting :: before a namespace name?

Tags: c++, namespaces, sys

Here `sys` is a namespace.
If we use `sys::xx`, I know exactly the meaning of `::`, but I saw a code, it's using

```
::sys::xx;
```

what's the meaning by putting `::` before a namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means: look in the global namespace (`::`) for something named `sys`. Then look in that scope (`class`/`struct`/`namespace`) for something called `xx`.